# How can I loop this python csv merging code?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
 source_files = sorted(Path('C:/folder/subfolder').glob('**/*.csv'))
    
dataframes = []
for file in source_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['date', 'cost'])
    dataframes.append(df)

all = pd.concat(dataframes)
all.to_csv('subfolder.csv',index=False)
```

How do i get the output to be named after each subfolder? I'm just trying to combine csv's within subfolders without combining ALL of them from ALL subfolders, and then naming the csv after the subfolder it was in.

Comment: take a look at `glob` documentation `**/*.csv` will descend directory structure

Comment: that combines all of it though, i need it combined by subfolder and named by the subfolder

Comment: you have all that in the `Path` object.  I re-organise my deeply nested media library in this way where I create directories if there are multiple files for a media component.  It's simple